# how can i use the strip_tag and remove html and css from me html string

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

i am trying to remove the HTML tag and CSS from my HTML string and truncate it .
please tell me how can i do it

i am tired to use strip_tags and HTML_safe

my code is

```
<%= @blogdetail.description.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We generally use a helper method we created called `clean` to do this:

```
def clean(content, length = 500)
    body = sanitize(content, tags: [])
    truncate(body, length: length, separator: " ")
end
```

This uses [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) to strip out any unwanted tags etc, and [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html) to slim the snippet down

You can call the method like this:

```
<%= clean(@your_html, 150) %>
```

Comment: sir some time its print such text . i thing it's not removing the &nbsp; and some other  (&lt;!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;&lt;xml&gt; &nbsp...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for that.

```
var str="<h1 style='color:red'>some text</h1> asdasda <div>again text</div>";
alert($(str).text());
```

It will give you only the text part of your string

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/60/)